# How to override text field to textarea in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, field, customization, rails-admin

First time I try to customize rails_admin and by default I am getting `text field` which I want to convert in `textarea`. In model I have given datatype as `string` So is that possible to display `textarea`?

**config/initializer/rails_admin.rb**

```
config.model Product do
    list do
      exclude_fields :id, :created_at, :updated_at
    end
    create do
     ......
     configure :description do
        partial 'my_partial_file' # to override field I have created partial file
      end
     .....
    end

  end
```

**views/rails_admin/main/_my_partial_file.html.haml**

```
= form.send field.view_helper, field.method_name, field.html_attributes.reverse_merge({ value: field.form_value, checked: field.form_value.in?([true, '1']), class: 'form-control', required: field.required})
```

I tried `html_attributes rows: 50, cols: 60` also tried to apply `custom_css` but doesn't help. Please guide me where I do mistake? And if possible please make me understand syntax of this `_my_partial_file`

**Edit:**
If I do something like this then I can get textarea

```
field :description, :text do # use second parameter to set field type
  required true        
  #partial 'my_partial_file'
end
```

But if I render partial then again `text_field` shown. :( I want text_area + partial file should also rendered as it contain other code to process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue by my own. I thought to delete this question but then realized if in future anyone faced same issue then my solution can be helped.

What I had changed in **`_my_partial_file`** is:

```
= form.text_area field.method_name, field.html_attributes.reverse_merge({ value: field.form_value, checked: field.form_value.in?([true, '1']), class: 'form-control', required: field.required})
........ # other piece of code
```

and in **config/initializer/rails_admin.rb** I have keep the code as it is:

```
   create do
     ......
     configure :description do
        partial 'my_partial_file' 
      end
     .....
    end
```

I got the reference from here: https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/obitum-rails_admin/0.0.5/files/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_text.html.haml#line=5 ([Wayback link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160319105259/https://docs.omniref.com/ruby/gems/obitum-rails_admin/0.0.5/files/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_text.html.haml))

and

http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/r/rails_admin_settings-0.8.0/app/views/rails_admin/main/_setting_value_html_haml.html

(Note: link dead. This may be the same file from that older version: https://github.com/rails-admin/rails_admin_settings/blob/v0.8.0/app/views/rails_admin/main/_setting_value.html.haml )